# App Store requiring iOS 8 Binary, remain compatible with iOS7

Tags: ios

According to https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a we now need to compile for iOS8. Does this mean if I submit a new app today, those using iOS7 can't install the app, even if I dont use new API's?

Answer (score 0):

NO, iOS 7 and earlier users can also your app that you build with iOS 8 SDK.

All depend on what Deployment Target you keep for your project.

[image]

I usually keep 7.0 because there are many features that are not available in iOS 6. The most difference is Arabic language support (especially with Font) as I am working in Arab countries and here we make most Arabic apps.

So in short if you keep Deployment Target is 8.0, then to download your app you have to have atleast iOS 8.0 & so on...

---

### Edit 1

***Building the app with iOS 8 SDK doesn't meant you need iOS 8 to run the app. iOS version required to run the app is related to deployment target.***

**Don't get confused...**

Comment: I'm not to comfortable with those settings, but in my understanding Apple is requiring us to set dev target to 8.0+ now?

Comment: @GeorgeL : No way, Apple can't force to set dev target to 8.0. Do you have a link stating Apple is requiring us to set dev target to 8.0?

Comment: @Downvoter : any reason for downvote? *I love to hate you...*

Answer (score 0):

It says according the apple new guidelines app you are uploading must have 64 bit support. Also the SDKs & third party libraries which you will use in app must be 64 supported.

Just make sure you did this in your app:

- Go to targets -> Build settings -> Add arm64 in valid architectures

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean if I submit a new app today, those using iOS7 can't
>   install the app, even if I dont use new API's?

No, It doesn't. But Apple warns you that your application will be rejected and
you can't submit it until you build it using iOS8 SDK, and add 64bit support.

Comment: By building it using iOS8 sdk mean that the app is incompatible with anything below 8?

Comment: No, you set valid architectures in your project settings(armv7, armv7s).
So your app will run on this devises.

Comment: @GeorgeL : Building with iOS 8 SDK doesn't meant you need iOS 8 to run the app... running the app is in related to deployment target... don't get confused...